# Snakemake - How to get all files in directory by subdirectories

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a directory that have several directories :

```
/test/cond1/
/test/cond2/
/test/cond3/
/test/cond4/
```

All subdirectories have several different files :

```
cond1 : a1.txt, a2.txt
cond2 : b1.txt, b2.txt, b3.txt
cond3 : c1.txt, c2.txt, c4.txt
cond4 : d1.txt,c2.txt, c4.txt, d2.txt
```

I'm using snakemake to run a command and I need to got all the files by cond separated with blank

I tried to do this :

```
def get_motifs_tf(wildcards):
    file_list = sorted(glob.glob("tf_final/{wildcards.cond}/*.bed"))
    return " ".join(file_list)
```

and this is my rule snakemake

```
rule compute_combi_enrichment:
    """
    For a given input, compute the enrichment in n-wise TF combinations using OLOGRAM-MODL.
    """
    input:
        query = 'input/core_silencer/{cond}/core_silencer.bed',
        excl = "input/exclude_region_dhs.bed",
        genome = "input/mm9.chromsizes"

    params:
        trs = get_motifs_tf,
        minibatch_number = 16, minibatch_size = 10   # Modulate depending on available RAM
    threads: 8                                       # Do not use 16 threads to not vampirize all the cluster

    output: 'output/ologram_result/{cond}/00_ologram_stats.tsv',

    shell: """
    set +u; source /gpfs/tagc/home/Apps/anaconda3/bin/activate dev; set -u
    gtftk ologram -z -c {input.genome} -p {input.query} --more-bed {params.trs} \
        -o output/ologram_result/{wildcards.cell_line} --force-chrom-peak --force-chrom-more-bed  \
        -V 3 -k {threads} -mn {params.minibatch_number} -ms {params.minibatch_size} \
        --more-bed-multiple-overlap --bed-excl {input.excl} --no-date \
        --multiple-overlap-max-number-of-combinations 80
    """
```

in --more-bed {params.trs}

I'm expected to get :

```
/test/cond1/a1.txt /test/cond1/a2.txt
```

Then

```
/test/cond2/b1.txt /test/cond2/b2.txt /test/cond2/b3.txt
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it :

The wildcards in function have to be convert in stp and without bracket :

```
def get_motifs_tf(wildcards):
    file_list = sorted(glob.glob("tf_final/"+str(wildcards.cond)+"/*.bed"))
    return " ".join(file_list)
```